# 12.10 installation with LUKS encryption & LVM in EFI mode

Tags: partitioning, 12.10, system-installation, uefi, lvm

I'm trying to figure out how to perform an installation of Ubuntu 12.10 (in UEFI mode) with LUKS encryption and LVM scheme. What I've done so far:

1. Booted on a GParted Live CD 0.14.1-6 in "UEFI mode only" (in the BIOS
   settings);
2. Created a GPT partition table with GParted;
3. Created one FAT32 partition  of 250 Mo at the beginning of the disk
   as "primary partition" with "boot" flag and "cylinder align" with
   GParted;
4. Rebooted the PC with an Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit DVD in "EFI mode only"
   (same BIOS settings);
5. Used "something else" option for installation type during the
   partitioning step;
6. Selected my free space and created a "Physical Volume for Encryption";
7. Set my key for the encrypted container.

Now I'm stuck there and can't figure out how to:

- Find how to create manually the LVM Physical volume, Volume Group and
  Logical volumes with this graphical installer;
- Determine what should I select for the bootloader (entire volume, sda_crypt volume...)

This topic is related to a brand new Ubuntu 12.10 installation, I opened a previous one for 12.04.1 installation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197521/how-to-install-in-efi-mode-with-encrypted-lvm)

Comment: I was running into the same issue. It seems unrelated to EFI, as LVM is unavailable in the GUI for manual installation. This is feature request [LP Bug #1042647: Manual Partitioning LVM (Ubiquity)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1042647). With the alternate CD being dropped, I think there's no workaround.

Comment: Switched to Ubuntu 12.10 server installer with the intention to add the desktop environment later on. Gone through the whole process : Boot on live GParted CD, create GPT partition table, EFi partition with "EFI" label & "boot" flag. Booted on a Ubuntu 12.10 server DVD. Installation was similar to the "old" 12.04.1 "alternate CD". Created my Physical volume for encryption, Logical volume group, and add all the logical volumes. INSTALLATION FAILED with the error: "can't install grub-dummy package". Is that [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1054323)?