# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS support

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, lts

I have been trying to install a dual boot Win8 & 12.04.1 Ubuntu 64 bit on an Asus N56V laptop but did no managed to preform the task (trying different tricks and Linux releases). I have encountered the notorious grub-install fatal error.

I have managed to perform the task by the use of Linux Mint 14 – Nadia (64 bit), but there is a small problem with the Network configuration.

Ubuntu 12.04 is defined as a Long term support release (aimed at 2017) but there are a significant amount of Linus users who encountered problems while trying to install a dual boot with Win 8/7.

Should Canonical consider releasing an upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 which solves the EUFI related issues and newer hardware? This would allow users to benefit from a stable Linux distribution.
The other option is to use an STS stable release that can tackle the mentioned problems.

Answer (score 2):

An upgrade, also known as a point release or 12.04.2, is scheduled for Feb 14 2013. It should include compatibility with UEFI, as well as better hardware support through a newer kernel, and integrate all updates and bug fixes.

Check out the [Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule) for more info.

Should you wish to try it now, or help [ISO testing](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/204/builds), [12.04.2 daily images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily/current/) are available.

Answer (score 0):

For your dual boot problem:

You can always install a wubi instalation, it comes with dual boot.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows

It creates a root.disk and swap.disk on your Windows part, and all your operations on Ubuntu are encapsulated in those 2 files. Basically when you are prompted to choose the drive space, your root.disk gets allocated that much space, and its like a virtual drive for Ubuntu.

You can't access it from within Windows, but you can edit and manage it from the Ubuntu part.

Comment: The Ubuntu 12.10 & 12.04.1 wubi (64 bit) failed to install.